# Sum of Arithmetic progression and Power of $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that Sum of any series in AP with common difference $d$ and first term = $1$ will be = $n^x$ where $d$ = $2($$n^{(x-2)}$ + $n^{(x-3)} + ... + n^0)$

I have a lengthy proof where solving for $d$ in $2n+n^2d-nd-2n^x=0$ (this can be achieved by basically rearranging standard AP sum formula) for each instance of $x$ and then generalize the same. However I am sure there has to be more elegant method to prove it for generic case.

Comment: Hi user3137471, welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: I have a lengthy proof where solving for d in  2*n+(n^2)*d-n*d-2*(n^x)=0 for each instance of x and then generalize the same. However I am sure there has to be more elegant method to prove it for generic case. I was just trying to figure out generalization by myself.

Comment: Put some part of it, or a brief summary of what you did in the question. It might help.

Comment: Hope the recent edit fixed what you guys have suggested, BTW idk what to use instead of "Prove" word :(

Comment: I am intrigued that there is no chance given before downvoting the question and there is no reason given for the same. May be this site is brutal for new comers like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;S_n\;$ is the sum of first consecutive $\;n\;$ elements:

$$S_n=\frac n2\left(2a_1+(n-1)d\right)=\frac n2\left(2+2(n-1)\left(x^{x-2}+n^{x-3}+\ldots+n+1\right)\right)=$$

$$n\left(1+(1+n+n^2+...+n^{x-2})(n-1)\right)=n(1+n^{x-1}-1)=n^x$$

This doesn't look very lengthy.

Comment: Well you are right. May be i couldn't phrase question correctly. It becomes easy to prove once we know $d$ = $2($$n^{(x-2)}$ + $n^{(x-3)} + ... + n^0)$ but may be I want to know how to directly arrive at the generalization.

Comment: @user3137471 Yes, it is easy when $\;d\;$ equals that, and I really don't know what you mean by "arrive at the generalization:.

Comment: Thx your proof guided me in right direction since when we solve for d we get $d = 2(n^x-n)/(n*(n-1))$ and simplification takes us to the generalization. I feel stupid now :)